# How can I rename uploaded file in Multer with progressive numbers?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I'm uploading images on the server and when I get the images in Express js using Multer, I'm not able to rename them with a progressive number like:
nameImage_1.jpg
nameImage_2.jpg
nameImage_3.jpg

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./assets/img/products/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
```

some ideas ??
THX

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you but I have it like this

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, __basedir + "/csvs/");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file.originalname);
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-name-${file.originalname}`);
    },
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but is not what I'm looking for... this just rename the images using a timestamp